# Parse Index.js and Cloud code

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

This may be a stupid question... But I don't know where to find the index.js file and the main.js file of the cloud code in my parse **android project**.

Comment: I think its important to provide more information with regards to your setup. Are you running parse-server or using Parse.com?

Comment: @SnakeBlisken I don't actually know the difference, but I think it may be Parse.com

Comment: Well the one is the current service from parse.com ( soon to expire ) or your own environment ( hosting ) with the open source server installed on it. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/

Comment: @SnakeBlisken Ohh, then I'm hosting my own environment.

Comment: where is your environment hosted? AWS, Heroku, Local?

Comment: @hybrdthry911 Heroku

Comment: @user3049535 Did you find out how to get a hold of the cloud code? I'm stumped on the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you using parse.com :**

You need to use parse.com `command line tool`: you edit locally in your machine, and then deploy your code. More info, in parse.com documentacion: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code

**If parse-server:**

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Configure your servers path on initilization. Then in the `main.js` you can place your code. Remember there is many ways to initilize the server. Just read the docs on the repo to better understand it.

```
cloud: '/home/myApp/cloud/main.js', // Absolute path to your Cloud Code
```

Use a ftp client to make things easier when editing the file etc. remember when making changes to the main.js file you will need to restart the parse-server again.

**For Heroku:**

Alot easier, just use there backend to set path for the cloud code. If the main.js file doesnt exsist. Just create your own one and stipulate a path to that file using the variable editor in Heroku backend.
[image]
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-a-parse-server-to-heroku#configuring-your-parse-server-with-config-vars

Comment: I think this may be it, I'm gonna try it.

Comment: The heroku example is what I NEEDED

Comment: I have set up ParsePush in my app but it does not send because I think I need to configure a index.js file. How do I do this for Heroku? I'm confused.